# ¿Cómo puedo asignar una variable local?

Tags: c#, variables

Me salta un error que dice uso de la variable local no asignada, ya he tratado de corregirlo pero persiste con el mismo error, necesito que el código me diga que número es perfecto y cual no

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NumeroPerfecto 
{
    class numero_perfecto 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
           int kat; nan; are
            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa un NUMERO para comprobar");
            nan = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            kat = 2;
            while (kat <= nan)
            {
                if (nan % kat == 0)
                {
                    are = are + (nan / kat);
                }
                kat = kat + 1;
            }
            if (are==nan) {
                Console.WriteLine(nan+" Es perfecto");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine(nan+" No es perfecto");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

El error salta para la variable "are" y ya no sé que más hacerle

Answer (score 1):

yo de hecho haría

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
```

asi lo inicializo, dando un valor inicial controlado, y añadiria control de errores

Answer (score 0):

Te indica error porque separas las variables con ;.

```
       int kat; nan; are
```

lo correcto es separarlas con , :

```
       int kat, nan, are;
```

o en su defecto poner varias lineas:

```
         int kat;
         int nan;
         int are;
```

Recuerda tambien, que en general hay que acabar las lineas con ; (hay ciertas excepciones, pero el de definir propiedades no es una de ellas)

Answer (score 0):

Como indica @Jakala, lo correcto es que definas las variables de forma correcta, ejemplo:

```
int a, b, c;

float x, y, z = 10.5;
```

Además, parece que tienes un warning porque no tienes la variable `are` inicializada.

Intenta inicializarla a 0.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, está mal hecha la definición de las variables:

```
//Así lo tenés vos:
int kat; nan; are

//así debería ser:
int kat, nan, are;
```

En su defecto, podés hacer tres lineas para definir las 3 variables:

```
int kat;
int nan;
int are;
```

Pero el error por el que estás preguntando es porque estás usando la variable `are` como un acumulador, pero no tiene un valor inicial.
Lo correcto sería que la definas de la siguiente manera:

```
int are = 0;
```

Con eso debería solucionarse tu error.